# How to get average of Arun's weight?

Tags: arithmetic

This is an aptitude problem I found in a [website, question no 9](http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/IBM/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-37851):

> In Arun's opinion, his weight is greater than 65 kg but less than 72 kg. His brother does not agree with Arun and he thinks that Arun's weight is greater than 60 kg but less than 70 kg. His mother's view is that his weight cannot be greater than 68 kg. If all are them are correct in their estimation, what is the average of different probable weights of Arun?

How can I solve this? Actually I am getting more confused at `different probable weights`. What is it meaning?

Comment: It's clear how to average the different *possible* weights, but if "the average of different probable weights" means "average weighted by probabilities" then you obviously haven't given us enough information to answer this.

Comment: @WillO, This is an aptitude question directly quoted from a website. I am confused myself. Here is the link: http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/IBM/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-37851 Check question no. 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all are correct, then Arun's weight can not be greater than 68 Kg and can not be less than 66 Kg. Thus average is 67 Kg.

Comment: How are you getting 66kg?

Comment: Since Arun thinks his weight is greater than 65 Kg, so it should start from 66 Kg

Comment: Seems correct so far, as the answer suggested in the website is too 67Kg.

Comment: But is it told that weight is always a whole number, say it may be 65.5 Kg.

Comment: No, that's not mentioned.